# JIRA (TEMPO) - Date is closed to registration

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Can someone explain to me how to use this function?

Tempo closes registration after three days and I would like to expand that to 14 days. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the Administration.
2. Go to the Tempo Section
3. Go to the scheduler sub-section
4. There is an explanatory table there with an "Operations" row. Click the "edit" link

**Congratulations you're now in one of the most-confusing JIRA configuration sections! :D**

So in your case:

- Set **type** do Biweekly.
- Set **Repeat on (Weekly)** to Friday.
- Set **Close** to 1 (working days after end date)
- Set the status reminders for **all users** and **late users**.
- Set **Send email to late users** to X hours (before closure). The X should be the value you like.
- Check the **Activate This Scheduler** check-box in order to make the settings active.
- **Save**

Now your period will be closed every two weeks. For further information consult the Tempo Documentation on [The Scheduler](http://wiki.tempoplugin.com/display/TEMPO/Configuring+Tempo+Scheduler) and [PeriodManagement](http://wiki.tempoplugin.com/display/TEMPO/Period+Management).

There is also the subject of [GracePeriods](http://wiki.tempoplugin.com/display/TEMPO/Grace+Periods). So what this means is that

> If a period has been closed for users by the Scheduler and some users
>   has not completed their timesheets, **Tempo Admin** can grant the users
>   a 'Grace Period' of any length from the 'User Action' list in the
>   '[Team Timesheet](http://wiki.tempoplugin.com/display/TEMPO/Team+Timesheet)' and 'Project Timesheet'.

How to use it is very well explained in the [Tempo Documentation link](http://wiki.tempoplugin.com/display/TEMPO/Grace+Periods) I provided.

Comment: wow thanks, i gave up on this question long ago and never cheched! Borislav you are the man!